# Using purrr to calculate differences across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to use purrr to calculate the difference scores between multiple fitness assessments.

Example dataframe would be like so:

```
PreA <- c(1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12)
PostA = c(2, 6, 10, 14, 16, NA)
PreB = c(4, 6, 8, 10 ,12, NA)
PostB = c(12, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17)
df <- data.frame(PreA, PostA, PreB, PostB)
```

I'm hoping to calculate the difference between the pre and post measures between all the columns (my actual data set has about 40), while ignoring NA and creating another column. I think the creating the other column will be easy with adding mutate, but I'm struggling in figuring out how to get purrr to work for this. Is there a tidy way to do this with purrr to avoiding copying and pasting?

I came across this code

```
  x %>%
   select(starts_with(y)) %>%
    rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
}

map(column_prefix, my_fun, x = df)
```

I think this could work, but I'm not sure how to get it to subtract instead of summing.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: There's no  `PreA` in your example.

Comment: @Maël apologies, I had it right next to the back ticks and didn't notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do with `tidyverse` functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -n, names_to = c("group", ".value"), names_pattern = "(Pre|Post)(.+)") %>% 
  group_by(n) %>% 
  summarise(across(A:B, diff, .names = "diff_{col}"))


# A tibble: 6 x 3
      n diff_A diff_B
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     -2      8
2     2      0      3
3     3      2      2
4     4      4      3
5     5      4      2
6     6     NA     NA
```

data

```r
PreA = c(4, 6, 8, 10 ,12, NA)
PostA = c(2, 6, 10, 14, 16, NA)
PreB = c(4, 6, 8, 10 ,12, NA)
PostB = c(12, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17)
df <- data.frame(PreA, PostA, PreB, PostB) 

  PreA PostA PreB PostB
1    4     2    4    12
2    6     6    6     9
3    8    10    8    10
4   10    14   10    13
5   12    16   12    14
6   NA    NA   NA    17
```

Comment: Can I just make sure I'm understanding the code correctly? Trying to learn R more. Mainly the first 2 lines with first being: split data frame into number of rows. I'm not entirely sure about the 2nd and don't think I have enough characters to ramble through. But is it basically: number of columns as inverse of n (row_number), use group (later defined as n) for column names, and combine with the pattern of Pre or Post? Not sure what the .+ signifies and couldn't find anything yet with google